# NullReferenceException when assigning dataset as datasource of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to assign datasource of a dropdownlist which is inside a gridview control. But when i am executing the following code i am getting NullReferenceException.

```
Protected Sub grvStudent_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Try
            Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim Query As String = "select Course from Courses"
            Dim Command As SqlCommand
            Command = New SqlCommand(Query, Connection)
            Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet()
            Connection.Close()
            Dim ddlCourse = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlCourse"), DropDownList)
            Da.Fill(Ds)
            ddlCourse.DataSource = Ds    //Exception is here
            ddlCourse.DataTextField = "Course"
            ddlCourse.DataValueField = "Id"
            ddlCourse.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the connection before filling the dataset and also you have not opened the connection so first open the connection then fill the dataset after that you can close the connection.

```
Protected Sub grvStudent_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Try
        Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim Query As String = "select Course from Courses"
        Dim Command As SqlCommand
        Command = New SqlCommand(Query, Connection)
        Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
        Dim Ds As New DataSet()
        Connection.Open()
        Dim ddlCourse = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlCourse"), DropDownList)
        Da.Fill(Ds)
        ddlCourse.DataSource = Ds    //Exception is here
        ddlCourse.DataTextField = "Course"
        ddlCourse.DataValueField = "Id"
        ddlCourse.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        Connection.Close()
    End Try

End If
End Sub
```

Edit :
   Add this line and run

```
   If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then

    //your binding code....

  Else

     MsgBox(ex.ToString)

  End If
```

For reference

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

Comment: I tried this. But the same exception on that line. I have 5 item in my course field and i will get 5 error message boxes.

Comment: have you checked the link which I have added in the answer there is complete example relating to your question.

Comment: Try ddlCourse.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0]; for the exception line

Comment: I tried that link to @Meherzad. I am stuck with this from yesterday and i visited maximum websites but this was a strange problem. I used Ds.Tables(0) too. But the result is same.

Comment: Try to debug your code check whether your dataset contains the any table or not here you can see the example or see my edited code

Comment: Ds.Tables.Count is 1. When i am displaying in a message box it shows 1. So that code wont do anything.

Comment: please post the whole exception which you are getting.

Comment: When i am checking in debug mode ddlCourse is nothing. So probably that will be the problem. Your code i s correct only.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your drop down is in the ItemTemplate section of the grid in your HTML code, you may have it in the edit section only ..

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Course">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourse" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourse" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```